# “Being with” definition

Tags: meaning, prepositions, context

If I said, “I get happier when I am with her.” Is it clear that “when I am with her” means when I am physically with her? “With someone” can mean a lot of things in English such as being in a romantic relationship or being in agreement with someone. Which meaning is correct in this context or are all correct?

Comment: The meaning is clear enough. The other meanings you've listed cannot possibly apply, you wouldn't say it that way then. But of course if you want to be more specific, you can be more specific. By using "by her side" or "in her company" or whatever. The usage of *with* is unremarkable. What's not unremarkable is the usage of *get*.

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: The default meaning is the archetypal one, in her (pretty immediate) presence. If an on-off relationship (as opposed to a constant relationship where one partner is forced to work away for longish periods) is meant instead, context is necessary to override the default reading, from pragmatics (Gricean maxim) considerations. If the 'on the same wavelength' reading is intended, again context is _needed_ (and the sentence sounds an odd way to convey this meaning in any case).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's about **spending time being physically with her**.

The speaker has noticed that when they're with her, they get happier, which implies a short term situation - when they are no longer with her, they are not as happy.

If it was something like "since I've been with her, I've been happier", then it could be about being in a relationship with her.